# Kotlin Pass Annotation as parameter to Annotation

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations

In Kotlin, I am trying to create an Annotation which can accept an array (`vararg`) of other annotations.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
annotation class MyAnnotation(
  vararg val annotation: Annotation
)
```

The problem is it tells me `Annotation` is not a valid parameter for annotation. If I try a specific annotation class, it works.

I'm trying to create an annotation which can take other annotations (for validations) and process them in order and do one unified effect.

Is there some special Kotlin syntax I can use to get it to let me provide an array of various annotation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe anything that is nullable (interfaces, Java types...) cannot be used as parameter to a Kotlin annotation. Maybe you could use

```
annotation class MyAnnotation(vararg val annotations: KClass<in Annotation>)
```

Comment: I did something similar in a slightly different context, though it didn't seem to like `<in Annotation>` so I ended up just having to go with `<*>` and validate after. However, for this use-case, the annotations may have parameters, so just accepting the class on its own isn't enough.